# Issue with Integrating PowerMockto with SCALA for tests with Maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, junit, powermock

I am trying to run my test with maven. The test are written in scala.

I have included the jars in pom.xml to include powermockito

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am currently using mockito-core:1.9.5

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am running my test with maven (Maven version 3.0.5) command like

```
 mvn clean test -Dtest=XMLWithZombieTest
```

Somehow the test are not executed while

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.zombie.server.XMLWithZombieTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.204 sec
```

My test is as below :

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Assert._

@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
class XMLWithZombieTest {

  var sb: StringBuilder = _
  var lb: ListBuffer[String] = _

  @Before def initialize() {
    sb = new StringBuilder("ScalaTest is ")
    lb = new ListBuffer[String]
  }

  @Test def verifyEasy() { // Uses JUnit-style assertions
    sb.append("easy!")
    assertEquals("ScalaTest is easy!", sb.toString)
    assertTrue(lb.isEmpty)
    lb += "sweet"
    try {
      "verbose".charAt(-1)
      fail()
    }
    catch {
      case e: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException => // Expected
    }
  }
}
```

As soon as I remove RunWith statement , my tests starts getting executed , but it is ignored when I have RunWith statement , which is required for PowerMockito.

I am using the below maven-surefire-plugin

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Suite*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I integrated PowerMockito similar with Java and it worked fine.

Any inputs would be helpful. Am I missing something. Let me know , if more details are needed.

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you post the actual tests?

Comment: Added the sample test above.